# How do i look at the relationships being created at Rails boot up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to see the wiring that is going on behind the scenes and double-check that i have defined my relationships correctly.

Comment: So what's wrong with your tests?

Comment: Seeing what is going on and verifying the relationships are two different things. To see what is happening behind the scenes, check out my answer, but if you want to verify that they are working properly, I would add tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're looking to do with the relationships, but every ActiveRecord subclass defines a method called "reflections" which you could use to inspect all of these relationships. Each reflection tells you what kind of relationship it is, what options there are, and tons of other info.

```
MyClass.reflections
```